# AngularJS $.ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.1.134:8888/pivot/api/report/uploadReport. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

I am getting this error.
Is anyone has an idea?

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": baseURL + "report/uploadReport",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "token": window.localStorage['token']
    },
    "data": {
        "rating": rating,
        "desc": desc,
        "spot_id": window.localStorage['spotId'],
        "image_name": path
    }
};

console.log(settings);
$.ajax(settings).done(
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

This is code part to call ajax.
Thanks

Comment: FYI - It is not a good practice to use Angular and jQuery together in 1 project. Btw, Angular has jqLite. Google it.

Comment: you might want to use Angular's $http service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Well it says its getting a 404 code so that means the page you are requesting cannot be found, are you sure your local server is reachable at that address?

Comment: 1:
You should use angular inside angular, not jquery.
2:
Message says that given url doesn't exist.
Are you sure that http://192.168.1.134:8888/pivot/api/report/uploadReport exist?

Comment: @RahulDesai it's not good practice to use jquery in controller and services but for directives you can't say that. so overall you can't say `It is not a good practice to use Angular and jQuery together in 1 project`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Why do you need jQuery in directives?

Comment: @RahulDesai can you elaborate why we use directives ? I think you'll get your question's answer from my question's answer

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi I have used directives for DOM manipulation. In the directive definition, I can do the DOM manipulation using vanilla JS. I do not see the need for jQuery. Correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: @RahulDesai we build directives make re-usable controls in order satisfy our businesses. It's may include dom manipulation . You are right we don't need external jquery in order to do that as angular use jqligtht if jquery is missing. But sometimes we need external plugins , library etc to cope up with our business then you have use it. That moment you can't stick with with term `It is not a good practice to use Angular and jQuery together in 1 project` . For directives angular didn't discourage using jquery.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi By jQuery external plugins, if you mean something like jQuery UI, there is [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and many more. I prefer to use minimum number of libraries so as to decrease load time. Also, I have seen a majority of developers use jQuery for DOM manipulation and plugins like you mentioned. I would achieve the same thing using vanilla JS/Angular/Angular UI Bootstrap. What do you think?

Comment: @RahulDesai most of the thing can be done by javascript then why need jquery ? Why you choose jquery , it depends on efficiency, scalabilty,maintainability  etc, factor and you never know when angular ui- team stop supporting this git with the version change of angular  and i am not talking about jquery UI . there are more libarary/plugin than this.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi True. I agree with you on Angular UI.

Comment: Member of Angular UI here.  We have no plans to drop support for UI-Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi.I noticed that it only happens when I add a header value. Please advise me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

404 means the server could not find the request resource.  You're hitting a URL without a defined route.  You'll need to tell your server what to respond with for that route.

Comment: I would also suggest using a tool like Postman to test the route before coding the ajax part.

Comment: I just noticed that this issue happens when I add a header field. Please advise me. Thank you